# how to Duplicate xml node using Varien_Simplexml_Element in magento

Tags: php, magento-enterprise, xml, simplexml

I am creating xml file programmatically. Where I am converting array to xml using following code:

```
 $xml = new Varien_Simplexml_Element('<MagentoOrder></MagentoOrder>');
 $this->array_to_xml($data,$xml);
 print_r($xml);
 $xmlData = $xml->asNiceXml();

 if(!file_exists($file)) {
     file_put_contents($file, $xmlData);
 }
```

Below is array_to_xml function:

```
protected function array_to_xml( $data, &$xml_data ) {
    foreach( $data as $key => $value ) {
        if( is_array($value) ) {
            if(is_numeric($key)){
                foreach($value as $k => $v){
                    if(is_array($v)){

                        $subnode = $xml_data->addChild($k);
                        $this->array_to_xml($v, $subnode);
                    }else{
                        $xml_data->appendChild("$k",htmlspecialchars("$v"));
                    }
                }
                continue;
            }
            $subnode = $xml_data->addChild($key);
            $this->array_to_xml($value, $subnode);
        } else {
            $xml_data->addChild("$key",htmlspecialchars("$value"));
        }
    }
}
```

Below is my array

```
 $s = array(
        "item" => array(
            "id" => 1
        ),
        "item" => array(
            "id" => 2
        )
    );
```

I want "item" should convert two times  as node. But output is following:

```
[item] => Array
            (
                [0] => Varien_Simplexml_Element Object
                    (
                        [id] => 1
                    )

                [1] => Varien_Simplexml_Element Object
                    (
                        [id] => 2
                    )

            )
```

Expected output is:

```
        [item] => Varien_Simplexml_Element Object
            (
                [id] => 1
            )

        [item] => Varien_Simplexml_Element Object
            (
                [id] => 2
            )
```

How to achieve this in magento?

Comment: You cannot have an array with 2 elements with the same key.